# How to 'lock a file for editing' using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an accounting program that many people will be using on a network. The program accesses files from the network, and those files can be edited by any user. The editing works by importing the file into the program, allowing the user to make changes and then opening the original file and replacing the old data with the changed data.

The problem is that if two people import the same file and both make changes, the second person to save the changes overwrites the first person's changes.

I realize that  I can have the program open the file in the background while it is being edited, which would lock it for editing by a second user. I am just nervous that the file will get corrupted by having it open. Is there any way for a user to lock the file for editing without actually opening the file, using VBA. That was I will only have it open for the moment I am replacing the data.

Comment: Is your program that imports the files also in Excel? So you have acess to VBA via your accounting program?

Comment: Yes and yes. The program is written using VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

- uses `SetAttr` to set the file specified under `strFile` as readony
- first a check is necessary that the file is not already open ([Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba))

**code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetAttribue()
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "c:\temp\test.xlsx"
If Not IsWorkBookOpen(strFile) Then
      SetAttr strFile, vbReadOnly
      MsgBox "file now readonly"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is already open"
    End If
End Sub
```

*checking sub*

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ff As Long
    Dim ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I thought of that. However, I am nervous that is the program crashes out for whatever reason (This is used by a whole firm, with many Dummies present), the file will remain Read-Only. I'm looking more for some sort of 'handle' that locks the file while the calling file is open.

Comment: @abegold in that case set the edited file to normal access on the `Workbook_Open` event of the master Accounting Program. Working with shared Excel files on a network is glitchy by nature, this is probably as good as you will get. Better would be changing to a storage process designed for multi-users.

Answer (score -1):

This is not working well, better option is to use:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70, 53, 52
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```