# Prevent Pasting to Same Row in Shared Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared spreadsheet that has both a form for users to enter data into and a log for the data to be moved to once the user hits the "submit" button (calls the Submit_to_Log sub). The macro works well in an unshared file; the only issue is when I share the file and two or more users try to submit data at the same time, the macro tries to write both of their data to the same, next blank row. The user who submits the data first gets their data submitted successfully, but the second user encounters an error where their data isn't submitted to the log but is still deleted from the form. Sheet3 refers to the log and sheet1 refers to the form. Any tips on how to improve this code?

```
Sub Submit_to_Log()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim rng_form As Range
erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Set rng_form = Sheet1.Range("B3:S" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row)
If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("K3").Value) Then
    MsgBox "First row must be filled!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If the first row is filled, please make sure that column K is filled out."
    End
End If
rng_form.Copy
Sheet3.Range("B" & erow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet3.Activate
Sheet3.Range("A1").Select
Sheet1.Activate
rng_form.EntireRow.Delete
MsgBox "Your requests have been submitted." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you still see requests in the form waiting to be submitted, please make sure that there are no empty rows between your requests and/or that each request has column K filled out."
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "There was an error. Please try again." 
End Sub
```

Comment: Create some form of locking mechanism ... e.g. exlusively lock a file and do the edit. If the file can't be locked ... wait until it can be. If it can't be locked in a reasonable period of time, give a time-out error. Or some variation of this type of approach.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler any tips on how to implement this? Never done it before

Comment: There should be plenty of examples you can google. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822361/how-to-lock-a-file-for-editing-using-vba