# Excel vba to check if a workbook has opened

Tags: vba, excel

IS there any way to check if an excel file is opened or not? If it is opened, then how can i close it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not start with a simple search? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373914/2119523

Comment: But there is no solution to close it

Comment: No, but you can tell by the votes which answer most people think is the best, and then _try_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workbook name does not include the period character, it can be as simple as:

```
Sub TestForOpen()
    Dim wb As Workbook, st As String
    st = "Phone"
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        stwb = Split(wb.Name, ".")(0)
        If st = stwb Then
            wb.Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

This one looks for an open workbook named Phone.xls or Phone.xlsx or ..................

If found the workbook is closed.