# How do I check if files are open and use them and if not open them?

Tags: file, vba, excel

I am using the code below to check if some files are open and get data from them, otherwise open them. When I run the program with the files opened it gives 'Subscript out of range' error.

```
Sub ReadDatafromOTWK()
    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim path1 As String
    Dim path2 As String
    Dim TWb As Workbook
    Set TWb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim OWb1 As Workbook
    Dim OWb2 As Workbook
    Dim Curdir As String
    'Clear data

    TWb.Sheets("OT WK").Range("B7:F1048576").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B7").Select
    Curdir = ActiveWorkbook.path
    path1 = Curdir & "\" & TWb.Sheets("Instruction").Range("B5")
    path2 = Curdir & "\" & TWb.Sheets("Instruction").Range("B6")
    'Check if the file is opened

    If IsFileOpen(path1) Then
        ' Display a message stating the file in use.
        MsgBox "File already in use!"
        '
        ' Error the line bellow
        Set OWb1 = Workbooks(path1)
        OWb1.Activate
        'GoTo 100
    Else
        ' Display a message stating the file is not in use.
        'MsgBox "File not in use!"
        ' Open the file in Microsoft Excel.
        Set OWb1 = Workbooks.Open(path1)
        OWb1.Activate
        'GoTo 100

    End If
End Sub

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? (And the first thing you should be doing when you have a problem is commenting out the lines that "turn error checking off", like the one you have at the start of `IsFileOpen()`.)

Comment: `Set OWb1 = Workbooks(path1)` What is path1 at the time of error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether Excel workbook is already open (using VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba is the second link on google when you search for "Detect whether workbook is open". Please see the answer and close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use the full pathname to refer to an open workbook with the workbooks property - but only its name