# Check if a certain pdf file is open and close it

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I use this code to export a pdf file from a word document.

Before exporting I need to check first if a file with the same name is already open, and if so close it then export.

I tried many things but had no luck.

```
Dim adbApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim adbDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim adbPageView As Acrobat.AcroAVPageView

Set adbApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set adbDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If adbDoc.Open("C:\Current Letter Preview.pdf", "") = True Then '==> If the file is not open, this line opens it
    adbDoc.Close (1) '==> Then close it

    If adbDoc Is Nothing Then '==> Doesn't understand that I want to check if any pdf files are open
        adbApp.Exit
    End If

    Set adbApp = Nothing
End If

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

If IsFileOpen("C:\TemporaryLetter.docx") Then
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wordApp.Documents("C:\TemporaryLetter.docx").Close '==> Is there something like that regarding acrobat IAC?
Else
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With wordApp
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = 2
    End With
End If

Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\TemporaryLetter.docx")

wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Current Letter Preview.pdf", _
ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

wordDoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

Set wordDoc = Nothing

If wordDoc Is Nothing Then
    wordApp.Quit
End If

Set wordApp = Nothing

Call adbDoc.Open("C:\Current Letter Preview.pdf", "")

adbDoc.BringToFront

Set adbPageView = adbDoc.GetAVPageView()

Call adbPageView.ZoomTo(0, 100)

Set adbDoc = Nothing
Set adbPageView = Nothing
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10):

To check if the file is open or not, you can see the code that I posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba/9373914#9373914) So the usage will be

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file path and name
    Ret = IsFileOpen("C:\Current Letter Preview.Pdf")

    If Ret = True Then
        MsgBox "File is open"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is Closed"
    End If
End Sub

Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

And to close a file, you will have to use APIs [FindWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml) and [PostMessage](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/PostMessage.shtml)

I have tested the code with Adobe Reader and hence in the code below, the name that I am searching for is `"Current Letter Preview.pdf - Adobe Reader"` You may have a different name. Please change as applicable.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
(ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassname As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

Sub Sample()
    Dim Hwnd As Long

    '~~> Find the window of the pdf file
    Hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Current Letter Preview.pdf - Adobe Reader")

    If Hwnd Then
        '~~> Close the file
        PostMessage Hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
    Else
        MsgBox "Pdf File not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Great Answer, also because it can be used to test for many file types by adjusting accordingly :)

Comment: Unfortunately for me when running `Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff` I get a permission error, which also can't be caught...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when I removed the - Acrobat Reader DC (64-bit) extension.
You need to delay the code by 50 milliseconds, or more if you want to use the same filename after closing the older version of the file.