# Status of a variable set to a workbook after the workbook has been closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple question (I think).  Let's say I set a global variable in a standard module in Book1 to an open (different) workbook:

```
Public Sub InitGlobals()
    Set gwkb = Workbooks("book2.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Now I close book2.xlsx manually.  What is the status of `gwkb`?  This is what I get when I run various tests in the immediate window:

```
?gwkb is nothing
False
?isempty(gwkb)
False
?isnull(gwkb)
False
```

However, if I ask for any property of `gwkb`, such as `gwkb.Name`, I get an automation error.

My question is:  is there a way to test for this condition, without resorting to some sort of "`On Error Resume Next`" test?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373914/2521004) is a good way to test if the workbook is still open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether Excel workbook is already open (using VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba)

Comment: @Gary's Student  & PortlandRunner -- Thanks for the quick response, but I don't really want to test if book2.xlsx is open. I want to know if it is still "safe" to use gwkb.  For example, in my application I won't know the exact filename that gwkb is set to, but if I try to use gwkb.Name, I get an error.  I guess I was wondering if there might be a status / test in VBA for gwkb beyond "is nothing", "isNull", or "isEmpty" to determine if it is still ok to use as an object.  Perhaps my only option is to write a function like "bIsOK(gwkb)" that checks for an error?  Thanks again.

Comment: if gwkb still exists , it's because you declared it as public or global, and not inside a sub/function, neither passed it as argument. So the variable name still exists, but is linked to an empty workbook (or object depending how you declared it -not shown in your code-)

Answer (score 1):

If *Book2* is initially open and may be closed then looping over the open books will not find it:

```
Public Sub InitGlobals()
    Dim gwkb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Set gwkb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
    gwkb.Close
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name = "Book2" Then
            MsgBox wb.Name & " is open "
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: `if not iserror(gwkb) then msgbox gwkb.name` , sometimes used after a `i= application.match ()` for testing if the i variable didn't return an empty result

Comment: by the way +1 for this nice way of not using error handle. could turn it into a function and use it often ^^

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier .....it is a trade-off....error-handling is not used, but looping is used.....this may loose efficiency if there are many workbooks open at the same time.

Comment: This answers the question "Is some workbook opened that happens to have the same file name as the workbook originally stored in `gwkb`?". It does not answer the question "Does `gwkb` contain a Workbook instance connected to an opened workbook?".