# VBA: Check Workbook Object is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook object previously created in code, all good.

However, for proper error handling, if the Workbook for whatever reasons gets closed, even though unlikely, I want to check this before further code execution.

The watch window shows the workbook after closure via direct entry (for simulation) with `<no variables>`:

[image: watches window]

However, nothing seems to work to check the workbook object is empty:

```vb
Debug.Print IsObject(dWorkbook) ' returns true > expected as obj as such still exists
Debug.Print IsNull(dWorkbook)   ' returns false
Debug.Print IsEmpty(dWorkbook)  ' returns false
Debug.Print TypeName(dWorkbook) ' returns object > expected

If dWorkbook Is Nothing Then    ' steps into Else
    Debug.Print "is Nothing"
Else
    Debug.Print "something"
End If
```

Thanks for a suggestion here to find a way to the check the workbook object has content.

Comment: A duplicate (no good answers): https://stackoverflow.com/q/26915981/11683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCount As Long
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    '~~> Put a breakpoint here and then close the workbook manually
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Check if there are worksheets
    wsCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wsCount = 0 Then MsgBox "WB is Lost" Else MsgBox "WB is Not Lost"
End Sub
```

If closing the other workbook manually is stopping the code, then use this method. Just add one Userform to your workbook so that you will be able to close the other workbook manually.

**Please note** *that adding the userform is only so that you can test the code manually. In a real scenario, you do not have to add a userform.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCount As Long
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    
    '~~> Put a breakpoint here and then close the workbook manually
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Check if there are worksheets
    wsCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wsCount = 0 Then MsgBox "WB is Lost" Else MsgBox "WB is Not Lost"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

## Check If Workbook Ran Out of Scope (Got Closed 'Accidentally')

### Edit

- You can use the [`TypeName` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function) to get the various 'states' of the variable:

```vb
Select Case TypeName(dWorkbook)
    Case "Nothing"
        MsgBox "The workbook is not set.", vbExclamation
    Case "Workbook"
        MsgBox "The workbook is set.", vbInformation
    Case "Object" ' or 'Case Else'
        MsgBox "The workbook lost scope.", vbCritical
End Select
```

- The following should be kind of a proof of the previous.

```vb
Sub SimpleTest()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
        MsgBox "My type name is """ & TypeName(wb) & """!" _
            & vbLf & "I'm not yet a ""Workbook"".", vbExclamation
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        MsgBox "My type name is """ & TypeName(wb) & """." _
            & vbLf & "I am a ""Workbook"".", vbInformation
    
    wb.Close False
        MsgBox "My type name is """ & TypeName(wb) & """!" _
            & vbLf & "I'm not a ""Workbook"" anymore.", vbCritical

End Sub
```

i.e., for someone who appreciates the subtle difference:

- The workbook was set and lost scope. It will return `False` if the workbook is in scope, and even if the variable is `Nothing` meaning that the workbook was not set.

```vb
Function DidWorkbookGetOutOfScope(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then DidWorkbookGetOutOfScope = TypeName(wb) <> "Workbook"
End Function
```

or, more practical:

- The workbook is set. It isn't `Nothing` and it didn't run out of scope.

```vb
Function IsWorkbookInScope(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    IsWorkbookInScope = TypeName(wb) = "Workbook"
End Function
```

### Initial Post

- Or try the following workaround.

**The Test (Usage)**

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    wb.Close False
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "It's nothing.", vbExclamation
    Else
        If HasObjectName(wb) Then
            MsgBox "It's still open.", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "It got closed!", vbCritical
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function HasObjectName(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
        HasObjectName = Len(obj.Name) > 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: This throws an 424 "Object required"

Comment: You need to set the following: `VBE->Tools->Options->General->Error Trapping->Break in Class Module` (Optionally, `Break on Unhandled Errors`).

Comment: Now all good.  Will use the HasObjectName Fuction. Thank you very much.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are closing the workbook using the code. `TypeName(wb) <> "Workbook"` will not give you the desired result if you manually close the workbook. If you want to see what I mean, then please see my post for a scenario that you can test.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Not sure what you mean. Try `SimpleTest`: if you out-comment the line `wb.Close False`, the last message will be a lie (*"I'm not a Workbook anymore."*). If you at this point create a breakpoint on the last message and manually close the workbook, it will become true again.

Answer (score 0):

As the workbook isn't closed by your code, I suppose the variable isn't reset.
You can use a check-Routine like this:

```vb
Public Function isWbValid(wb As Workbook) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim c As String
   c = wb.Windows(1).Caption
   isWbValid = Err = 0
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Then you can use it like this:
`debug.print isWbValid(dWorkbook)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the function throws an automation error. Have tried earlier to check also if for example wb.name exists but this is throwing same error.

Comment: Hmm - where do you get the error?

Comment: Here: c = wb.Windows(1).Caption

Comment: But there is an `On error resume next` - you shouldn't get an error ... except you are in a class module and have the option set to break errors.