# Check to see if word document is open before opening

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a basic macro that opens up a word document, which works just fine. However if the document is already open then a new 'read-only' version is loaded. Is there a way to check if the document is already open, and if so switch to it rather than open a new copy.

```
Sub Open_Word_Document()

    Dim objWord As Object

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template.docx"

End Sub
```

EDIT:
This has been edited to suggest this question is already answered, but as the comments state the suggested question is referring to a different MS Application.

Comment: The answer may be here, should be the same with word: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba

Comment: That seems Excel Workbook specific, I will try to see if it can check for Word Documents also.

Comment: I forgot that Word doesn't have workbooks. Maybe you should try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209189/de

Comment: Thats a good start thank you, now I need to work out why its throwing up `Error 70 - permission denied`

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039182/check-if-word-document-is-already-opened-error-handling