# Check if Word Document is already opened + Error Handling

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hello and thank you for your answers in advance.

I am opening a word document using excel-vba and save it under a new name. 
This is actually working fine.

But problems occur if the word document with the new name is already opened!

Let's say there is a button to run the script and the user runs it the second time, and has the created file still opened. The user might change something in excel and now wants to check how the new word document would look like afterwords. He will click the button again. 
It will open the template (do all changes) and try to save it, but can't because it is already opened and it might save this document with the old name (template) instead of a new file. Therefor it will overwrite and destroy the template file (got this several times during testing)!

Therefore I am in need of some proper code and a better Error-Handling. My first thought is to check if the document with the filename already exists. But it does not quite do its job:

```
Sub CreateWordDocument()
    Dim TemplName, CurrentLocation, DocumentName, Document As String
    Dim WordDoc, WordApp, OutApp As Object

    With table1
        TemplName = table1.Range("A1").Value 'Get selected template name
        CurrentLocation = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'working folder
        Template = CurrentLocation + "\" + TemplName
        DocumentName = .Range("A2").Value
        Document = CurrentLocation + "\" + DocumentName + ".docx"

    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'if Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    End If

    'if document is already opened in word than close it
    'if its not possible to close it - end application to prevent any damage to the template
    On Error GoTo notOpen
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents(DocumentName + ".docx")
    On Error GoTo closeError
        WordDoc.Close
    notOpen:
        'Open the template
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=Template, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
    'save with new name
    WordDoc.SaveAs Document
    closeError: 
    'open a message box and tell user to close and run again.
```

At the current stage it just jumpes from "Set WordDoc = WordApp. ..." to notOpened. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: If the Word documents are intended to be "templates", then don't allow *any* changes to them. Make the files read only, and give the user a copy instead of the original.

Comment: You could save the template as an actual template (`dotx` or `dotm` extensions) and use that `Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\<path>\MyTemplate.dotx")` - it will open as `Document1`, `Document2`, etc.

Comment: Darren's comment is correct. Use `Documents.Add` to create a copy of the original file so that the original will not be over-written. This method can be used also with docx-type files.

Comment: This topic (not overwriting the original file) comes up regularly and has been answered often. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703241/copying-contents-of-word-doc-to-newly-created-word-doc-from-excel-vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying contents of Word doc to newly created Word doc from excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703241/copying-contents-of-word-doc-to-newly-created-word-doc-from-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function:

```
Public Function FileIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim ff As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    FileIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Then use in your code:

```
If Not FileIsOpen(DocumentName & ".docx") Then
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=Template, ReadOnly:=False)
Else
    'Do something else because the file is already open.
End If
```

The document name must be the full path to the document.

---

*Couple of other things:*

Only `Document` is a string, and `OutApp` is an object.  All other variables are `Variants`.

```
Dim TemplName, CurrentLocation, DocumentName, Document As String  
Dim WordDoc, WordApp, OutApp As Object
```

It should be:

```
Dim TemplName As String, CurrentLocation As String, DocumentName As String, Document As String
Dim WordDoc As Object, WordApp As Object, OutApp As Object
```

---

VBA generally uses `+` for addition, and `&` for concatenation.

```
DocumentName + ".docx"
```

would be better written as

```
DocumentName & ".docx"
```

---

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document) is a reserved word in `Word`.  It shouldn't cause too much problem here as the code is in `Excel`, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: This does not work on my machine. The function `fileIsOpen` returs TRUE even if the file is not open.

Comment: @genespos I didn't check for that - I'd usually use other code to check if the file exists before getting to this function so didn't consider it.  Good catch though.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because my solution was wrong (your reply was too quick) I solved by adding a check if file exists (to prevent wrong answer of the code)

Comment: @genespos now I can't delete my comment.... it'll look like you're talking to yourself. :D