# Check if excel file is open, if yes close file,if no convert csv file to excel Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem creating a condition. Please see pseudo code below. thanks in advance

Check if File A.xls is open
    If File A.xls is Open

```
    Close File A.xls
Else

    Convert File A.csv to .xls

End If
```

Convert File A.csv to .xls

```
Dim DeleteEntries As Workbook
Dim WorksheetDeleteEntries As Worksheet
Dim WbOpen As Boolean

'Convert Acc_FR044_SAP.csv to excel
strDir = "C:\FR044 Automated Checker\"
strFile = Dir(strDir & "Acc_FR044_SAP.csv")

If Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls") Is Nothing Then ' IM HAVING AN SUBSCRIPT ERROR IN THIS LINE

    WbOpen = False

Else
    Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False

End If


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While strFile <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDir & strFile, Local:=True)
wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8
wb.Close True

Set wb = Nothing
strFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: where exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: It prompts an subscript error on this line.
If Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls") Is Nothing Then

Comment: if that workbook is closed you can't check it existence in this way `Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls"` as there is any object of that type & name. You can try solution provided below in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this solution which works for current instance of Excel:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim tmpWB As Workbook
Set tmpWB = Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls")
On Error GoTo 0

If tmpWB Is Nothing Then 

    WbOpen = False

Else
    tmpWB .Close SaveChanges:=False

End If
```

Comment: This method works; No Doubt. However it is unreliable if the workbook is opened in a different excel instance like @brettdj mentioned :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to check if the file was open in any instance, on any machine

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim bFileOpen As Boolean
    bFileOpen = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\yourfilename.xlsx")

    If bFileOpen Then
        MsgBox "File is open"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is Closed"
    End If
End Sub
```

*testing function from Microsoft example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860143/check-if-excel-file-is-open-if-yes-close-file-if-no-convert-csv-file-to-excel-v/30862618#comment49767930_30862618)*

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long
    Dim ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0
    IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70
    IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: downvoted as no one is asking for such solution and your answer in too sophisticated to simple OP's problem.

Comment: ++ A more reliable way of checking. I also use the same logic as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba/9373914#9373914)

Comment: What does 'OP' mean ?

Comment: @iDevlop: Depends on how you use it. `Original Poster`. `Original Post`

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language but where in the question you find something like `if file is open on any instance of Excel or anywhere?`. What I see in question is default and most common situation - `if file is open on my current Excel instance` and it seems that I was right with my answer. Indeed, you did a blindly downvoting and indeed you are right with your answer which I know and use in situations where necessary. There is no need to use it here if you have simple solution available. Don't you think we could be both right?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor your code certainly works fine on the current instance, but as current instance wasn't  actually specified, and the code I provided hardly *complex* then why would you look for a robust solution rather than a partial one. If you edit your code (so I can change my vote) then I will remove my down vote given you have taken the trouble to explain why you posted as you did. Cheers.