# Reference opened Wokrbook & Create error message if workbook is in use

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Hi I have the below code, I would like to reference the workbook so I can copy and paste data from an already opened work book. However I am struggling to reference the workbook correctly. Can anyone help? :)

File name is "Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm"

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm"

Dim PicsFile As String
PicsFile = "Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm"
```

I would also like an error message to occur if someone else is currently in the file name "Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm" I.e. if another user is in the file it will exit the macro. (I'm not too sure how to do this)

Thanks

Comment: to check if file is already open see:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open-using-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Mielks answer which will allow you to reference the correct workbook - in the same line you can also have the file open as read-only.

This code will tell you if a file is already open - returning TRUE or FALSE (it will also return TRUE if the file doesn't exist - either way it will say if you can do anything with that file name and location).

```
Public Function FileIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim ff As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    FileIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Public Sub test()

    If FileIsOpen("S:\Bartrup-CookD\MyTestFile.xls") Then
        MsgBox "That file's open, or doesn't exist - do something else."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
    "U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm")
```

Comment: Thanks! your help is much appreciated.