# Opening a workbook (or other Office doc) on a shared drive that another user has open

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

Suppose a workbook exists on a shared network drive, and is open by User A.  If User B attempts to open this file by double clicking it, he gets something like the following prompt:

[image]

If User B instead attempts to open the workbook programmatically (perhaps with an add-in) using:

```
Workbooks.Open("N:\path_to_workbook\workbook.xlsx")
```

**what happens, exactly?**  Does this above prompt appear?  If so, can it be suppressed with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?  If `Workbooks.Open` as shown above throws an exception in this case, do we need to try again using the ReadOnly argument, as:

```
Workbooks.Open("N:\path_to_workbook\workbook.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
```

I have read other posts (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open)) that suggest that `Workbooks.Open` in the *first* code snippet succeeds and the workbook is opened read-only, although this is not perfectly clear.

Unfortunately, I don't have a test environment configured to replicate this scenario myself, which would otherwise be the obvious answer.

Comment: you don't have a test environment? can't you just test the concept in a random excel file? The `ReadOnly` argument should do the trick.

Comment: The prompt appears, and remains to appear, even if  `DisplayAlerts` are turned off. If you include `ReadOnly=True` it will then open the workbook without the prompt.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, no, per my post I do not have a test environment that includes a shared network drive and another user.  No, you cannot test this in a random workbook; try double clicking a workbook in Windows Explorer that is already open.  Yes, the ReadOnly argument would certainly do the trick, but defaulting to opening workbooks read-only is undesirable.

Comment: @Iturner, if this is indeed correct, then please post it as an answer.  I must admit that I am skeptical that you get the prompt when you try to open the workbook programmatically, but since I cannot test it myself...

Comment: You can run a check to see if the workbook is open first, and if it is, then open it `ReadOnly`, if that is acceptable, or just alert the user that the workbook is open and can't be worked with at the moment.  See this post for more, if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, that is the post to which I linked in my OP, and seeks to answer a different question.  I don't need to check whether the file is open before trying to open it depending on the answer to my question.

Comment: Apologies, I did not open that link. My thought was that you can open as ReadOnly  *only* if need be, based on your last statement in your last comment.

Comment: You've got a lot of tags on this post. When I open a workbook via VBA and someone else on the network has it open, it opens as read-only with no prompt. I have no idea about C# or VB.Net.

Comment: Thanks, Dick.  The relevant code is basically the same for VBA, VB.NET, and C#, hence the tags.  Accordingly, the result that you observed would be the same for C# and VB.NET.  For everyone's benefit, I want to point out that this directly contradicts what @Iturner suggested above.

Comment: Are you asking if you can "get around" the popup and have two people editing the workbook simultaneously by opening it programmatically? If so, the answer is **no**.

Comment: @Blackhawk, not asking anything other than what is asked in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on our network drive environment, and found the following.  If the file is opened by User A and User B attempts to open the file programmatically using `Workbooks.Open` then the result **will be** a Read Only version of the file.

If you wish to control the opening of Read Only files than you may utilize the following code example to close it:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Path_To_Excel_File")
If wb.ReadOnly Then
    MsgBox "File already in use"
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
End If

End Sub
```