# I want to know how to link between two workbook in microsoft excel using vlookup via vba method

Tags: excel, vba

I've got 2 file: 
`vlookup.xlsx` and `test.xlsx`

This is what I typed in VBA:

```
Sub Loop8()

    Dim filename1 As String
    filename1 = "C:\Users\tom\Desktop[vlookup.xlsx]"

    Do

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4"),Range("AB2")=vlookup(Y2,"& filename1 & "Sheet1!$Y:$AB),4,false)"

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1))

End Sub
```

PS: `Y2` is being reference to the product code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work for you.

```
Sub Loop8()
    Dim fileName As String, filePath As String
    Dim lookupWB As Workbook
    Dim lookupWS As Worksheet, currWS As Worksheet

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim book2Name As String

    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    fileName = "vlookup.xlsx"
    filePath = "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\" & fileName
    If IsBookOpen(fileName) = False Then Workbooks.Open (filePath)
    Set lookupWB = Workbooks(fileName)
    Set lookupWS = lookupWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    currWS.Range("AB2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currWS.Range("Y2").Value, lookupWS.Range("$Y:$AB"), 4,False)        
End Sub
```

**IsBookOpen** Function:

```
Function IsBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

IsBookOpen function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open/9373914#9373914) written by @SiddharthRout

Comment: Thanks for helping :D  I have another solution for the problem