# Handling erros for Application.Workbooks without using Error handlers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign an opened workbook to an workbook object. If that workbook is not already opened, then it throws an error. I am handling the errors using an Error Handler.

This works for me:

```
On Error GoTo OpenWorkbookError

Set Uwk = Application.Workbooks(WbkName)

OpenWorkbookError:
If Err <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  MsgBox ("Please Open the Required Workbook")
  Exit Sub
End If
```

But is there a way to avoid using the error handlers in this situation.

Comment: What's wrong with google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open

Comment: @SJR Saw those exact answers. But the functions declared use the error handlers.

Comment: Then I think it's safe to say that for all intents and purposes this is one of those occasions where impossible to avoid.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible - switching through all opened workbooks and matching the names with the required one, should do it for me without the error handlers. But it consumes time, that's why I didn't opt for that yet.

Comment: You've answered your own question then! Strictly speaking this isn't an SO question as your code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is check each workbook name, but what's wrong with the functions in the link that @SJR gave?

In your provided code you've kept the error handler within the main body of code - it should appear between the `Exit Sub` and `End Sub` at the end of the procedure.

Something like this would work without an error handler, but it's slower as it needs to check each workbook:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Uwk As Workbook
    Dim WbkName As String

    WbkName = "PERSONAL.XLSB"

    For Each Uwk In Workbooks
        If Uwk.Name = WbkName Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Uwk

    If Not Uwk Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Uwk.Name & " found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Your version of the code should have the error handler outside the main body:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim WbkName As String
    Dim UWk As Workbook

    WbkName = "PERSONAL1.XLSB"

    On Error GoTo OpenWorkbookError

    Set UWk = Workbooks(WbkName)

TidyExit:
    'Close anything that needs closing and Exit.

Exit Sub  '<< End of main body of procedure.

OpenWorkbookError:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9 'Subscript out of range.
            MsgBox "Please open the required workbook."
            Resume TidyExit
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
            Resume TidyExit
    End Select

End Sub  '<< End of procedure.
```