# Exclude system and open files when searching in folder

Tags: vba, excel

My code searches folders and sub folders. I want to be able to exclude open files or system files when processing each file in these folders. Any help would be great!

```
Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder("folderpath")

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        If UCase(oSubfolder.Name) <> "DO NOT USE" Then
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Else
        End If
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        'Process each file but exclude files such as "~xxxxxx" or thumbs.db or xxxx.tmp files
    Next oFile
Loop
```

Comment: are you only looking to process actual Excel files? Or also `.txt` or `.csv'?

Comment: all .xlsx files only, but when i do it, i'm getting ~xxx.xlsx files and temp and db files along with it. I don't need those files.

Comment: Use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open/9373914#9373914) to check if the file is already open

Comment: Use [THIS](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-getattr-function.html) to check if it is a system file or not

Comment: and add `If oFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then` as a condition inside your `For Each oFile` loop to process.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GetAttr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getattr-function) should help you.

This should exclude any hidden or opened files:

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files 
    If (GetAttr(oFile) And vbHidden) = 0 Then 'Process files that are not hidden
        '
        '~~> Do what you want
        '
Next oFile
```