# VBA to check if file is open

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have the following code which is supposed to check if a file is open or not.  If the file is open then it should do nothing but if the file isn't open then it should display a message saying that the file isn't open and exit the sub.

However, it always exits the regardless if the file is open or not.

```
Sub Update_Folder()

Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String





'Creates file string name
str = Range("H6").Value
openPos = InStr(str, "[")
closePos = InStr(str, "]")
midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)


   If Range("B2").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B4").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B5").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B6").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B9").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B12").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B13").Value = "Yes" Then

On Error Resume Next
    Set WB = Workbooks(midBit)
    If Err Then MsgBox ("Please open the following file(s): " & str)
    'Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
 End If


Call Folder_Creation

END SUB
```

What is the correct syntax to check if a file is open and if so do nothing but if the file is not open display a `msgbox` and exit sub?  Cell `H6` is `C:\Users\User1\Documents\[TestFile.xlsx]`.

I tried the solution from the following link but
[Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open)

It does not work for me.  Maybe cause I am setting the path based on a file path in a cell?  I get a file not found error when running it.  The `debug` screen takes me to the `Case Else: Error ErrNo` line.

UPDATE:

The following code works for me.  I had to change `Error GoTo` syntax and then move `error handler` to the end of the script.  So if the error occurs it skips to the bottom of the script

```
Sub Update_Folder()

Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String

'Creates file string name
str = Range("H6").Value
openPos = InStr(str, "[")
closePos = InStr(str, "]")
midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)


   If Range("B2").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B4").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B5").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B6").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B9").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B12").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B13").Value = "Yes" Then

On Error goto ErrorHandler1:
    Set WB = Workbooks(midBit)
    If Err Then MsgBox ("Please open the following file(s): " & str)
    'Exit Sub



Call Folder_Creation


 ErrorHandler1:

MsgBox ("Please open the following file(s): " & str)
    Exit Sub



END SUB
```

Comment: What kind of file? A workbook?

Comment: Correct, a workbook.

Comment: What string does midbit return? Can you show it here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be of help:

Macro code to check whether a file is already open

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Follow the instructionsin the link above. Which are as follows: In Excel, Press Alt+F11 to bring up VBA. Click Insert > Module. Copy and paste the code. Go back to Excel and set up the cells as in the picture below. This is how your cells should be setup:

[image]

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work for me.  Cell `H6` contains the file path and when I dim it as a string(str) to be called as ` If IsFileOpen(str) Then` based on the link you shared, I get an error.  The error iget is either file not found or I don't have access which I do have access.  Also the `debug` screen takes me to the `Case Else Error errnum` section.

Comment: @AlmostThere I don't get what you're saying. You don't need to dim anything as a string. Press Alt+F11. Click Insert > Module. Copy and paste the code. Go back to Excel and set up the cells as in the picture above.