# How would I prevent multiple users from editing the same Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever a specific Excel file is in use, I'd like to prevent anyone else editing it.
ie. "This file is currently being edited by John Dow, and it will now close".

I'm looking for something simple.
Any ideas?

Thank you,
D.

Comment: Excel is single user by default - as long as you haven't made it a shared workbook then a second user will open a read-only version of the file.  I don't think you can get who else has it open, but you could check if it's opened in read only and close if it is?

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an answer to this which I'll have to say is nowhere near perfect (blatantly trying to avoid down-votes for trying to do something that isn't really necessary).
I just wanted to see if you could extract the name of the person that has it open - after all, it does *normally* give the name of the person who has it locked for editing when you first open a workbook.

When you open an Excel file a hidden lock file is created in the same folder.  The lock file has the same name as the original with `~$` appended to the front of the file name.
I found you can't copy the lock file using the VBA `FileCopy` as you get a `Permission denied` error, but you can using the `FileSystemObject` `CopyFile`.

The thinking behind my method is to copy the lock file and change it to a text file.  You can then pull the user name from it and compare it against the current user name - if it's different then report that and close the file.

**Note** - I wouldn't use this in a project as there seems to be a few places it can fall over, and Excel will generally tell you that someone else has it open anyway.  It was more of a coding exercise.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ff As Long
    Dim sLockFile As String
    Dim sTempFile As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim XLUser As String, LoggedUser As String
    Dim fle As Object

    sLockFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "~$" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    sTempFile = Replace(sLockFile, "~$", "") & "tmp.txt"

    'Create copy of lock file as a text file.
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    oFSO.CopyFile sLockFile, sTempFile, True

    'Read the first line from the text file.
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open sTempFile For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Line Input #1, XLUser
    Close ff

    'Remove the current user from the text.
    'Need to check this so that it doesn't close because it sees the current user name.
    XLUser = Replace(XLUser, Application.UserName, "")

    'Extract name from text string.
    'There is a double space in the InStr section.
    'The double exclamation mark is a single character - I don't know the code though.
    'Unicode U+0203C I think.
    XLUser = Replace(Left(XLUser, InStr(XLUser, "  ") - 1), "", "")

    'Remove hidden attributes so temp file can be deleted.
    Set fle = oFSO.GetFile(sTempFile)
    fle.Attributes = 0
    Kill sTempFile

    'If there's still text then it's a user name - report it and close.
    If Len(Trim(XLUser)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Workbook is already open by " & XLUser
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

End Sub
```

Having put all that, this code is probably safer:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "Is opened in read only.", vbOKOnly
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

End Sub
```