# Error when determining whether excel file is already open

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to use the code from the following post to determine whether a different excel file is open:

[Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open)

but my code was errorring out every time.  After a bit of testing, I determined it appears to be because I have spaces in the filename/path.  Is there a way to allow for the file path to include spaces?

Comment: Can you share your particular code by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53675619/edit)ing your question?

Comment: Please paste a short, reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole path and filename in double quotes if you have spaces in your file name.

So if you have a vba path & file name of:

```
WBPath = WB.Path & Application.PathSeparator & WBName
```

You need to add double quotes to the beginning and end of the string.

```
WBPath = """" & WB.Path & Application.PathSeparator & WBName & """"
```

What is `""""`? (The string starts with a " then the next two " " resolve to be a single double quote of text, then the last " ends the string.)

So you are in essence concatenating a Double Quote to the front of the path\file name and to the end.

Hope that helps. :)