# I need to check whether a file(test.xls) is open or not

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check whether a file(test.xls) is open or not. If it is already open then show a msgbox "Open" else show a message box "Open the file" How can I do that?

```
  On Error GoTo nofile
    Windows("So Deit.xls").Activate
    MsgBox "File Open"

nofile:
    Workbooks.Open fileName:="C:\Users\ds\Desktop\New folder\So Deit.xls"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format better. Separate the title from the contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open)