# Issues with Working and Activating Multiple Workbooks excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some issues when working with calling and working with multiple workbooks.  I have a macro that updates some excel sheets using some data.  All 5 of those spreadsheets are assigned a variable with the filename and the file path. When I run a second SUB / Macri to Save and Close all 5 of those workbooks after they are done updating - It doesn't select the right workbooks even though they've been assigned the same variable names as the previous macro.  So I believe my issue is - If the workbooks are already open I can't associate a variable too them.  - I assume that if the file name and file path are right, the workbooks open can be set as variables and then be able to close them - Thoughts?

```
    Sub CloseWorkbooks()

    Dim MB, WB1, WB2, WB3, WB4, WB5 As Workbook
    Dim FP1, FN1, FN2, FN3, FN4, FN5 As String


    FP1 = "G:\DATA......"

        FN5 = "Book1.xlsx"
        FN2 = "Book2.xlsx"
        FN3 = "Book3.xlsx"
        FN4 = "Book4.xlsx"
        FN1 = "Book5.xlsx"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FP1 & FN1)
            WB1.Activate
            WB1.Save

            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
            WB1.Close


                Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FP1 & FN2)
                WB2.Activate
                WB2.Save
                'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
                WB2.Close


                    Set WB3 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FP1 & FN3)
                    WB3.Activate
                    WB3.Save
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
                    WB3.Close


                        Set WB4 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FP1 & FN4)
                        WB4.Activate
                        WB4.Save
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
                        WB4.Close


                            Set WB5 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FP1 & FN5)
                            WB5.Activate
                            WB5.Save
                            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
                            WB5.Close



End Sub
```

This works if the worksheets are NOT Open, but it doesn't work if the worksheets are open - which is what I want it to accomplish.  The previous macro opens all the worksheets and updates them.  I want this macro (2nd one shown above) to save and close all the workbooks.

-Thank you.

Comment: Are the workbooks open when you run this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `Workbooks.Open(...)` with a call to this it should return the workbook if its open, and open and return it if it is not.

```
Public Function getWorkbookByFileName(ByVal FileName As String) As Workbook
Dim Book As Workbook: Set Book = Nothing
Dim Count As Integer: Count = Application.Workbooks.Count
Dim Index As Integer: Index = 1
Do
    If Application.Workbooks(Index).FullName = FileName Then
        Set Book = Application.Workbooks(Index)
        Exit Do
    End If
    If Index < Count Then
        Index = Index + 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
If Book Is Nothing Then
    Set Book = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileName)
End If
Set getWorkbookByFileName = Book
End Function
```

This is fairly long winded, looking at some of the answers to [Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9373082/212869) I see that it can be achieved without looping through the workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

This will close the correct workbook.

```
Sub CloseWorkbooks()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 6
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\DATA......Book" & i & ".xlsx")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next i
Exit Sub
```