# VBA code stopping when secondary workbook manually closed (waiting for user to close second workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to have primary workbook (WorkbookA), open a second workbook (WorkbookB) and test for a value within it.  Value to match is in WorkbookA, cell B3 and is the number 1.   Range to test in WorkbookB is "A:A".

If the value is not found, WorkbookB is reopened for the user to edit (will optimize to reduce opening/closing, any ideas on getting user input to resume would be appreciated after editing Workbook B), and the code in WorkbookA loops and retests if WorkbookB is still open every 10 seconds.

After the user edits WorkbookB to ensure the value is present, they close it (any better way to signal they are complete is welcomed so I don';t have to close and reopen the files.  They are small, so it's not an issue for speed, just seems inefficient).

The assumption I had was that the code would then detect the workbook was closed and then continue code execution, but the VBA is stopping as soon as I select the X in the top right corner of Workbook B.

Would prefer not having separate code in personal.xls file because of multiple users.

Thanks,
Aaron

Code in Workbook A:

```
Global Const strWBb As String = "C:\Users\ashepherd\Desktop\WorkbookB.xlsx"
Global Const strRng As String = "A:A"

Sub Validate()

' *****************************    CHECK WORKBOOKB FOR 1 IN COLUMN A:A  *****************************
'  Verify presence on item in second workbook

searchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value


Do While Verify(searchItem, False) = False
        Call Verify("", True)
        Do While IsWorkBookOpen(strWBb) = True
            endTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now())
            Do While Now() < endTime
                DoEvents
            Loop
        Loop
        Debug.Print "Workbook closed"
Loop


Debug.Print "search item found"



End Sub



Function Verify(item, OpenOnly As Boolean) As Boolean


' ****************************************************************************
'  Open workbook B and verify that presence of item
' ****************************************************************************

Dim wbVerify As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range

' ************************** OPEN FILE ************************************************
If IsFile(strWBb) Then
    Set wbVerify = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strWBb, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)    '  Open WorkbookB
    wbVerify.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Else
    MsgBox " File path incorrect.  Unable to open.", vbCritical
    Exit Function
End If

' ************************** TEST FOR ITEM ************************************************
If OpenOnly = True Then             ' Only opening the file for read/write.  Not testing values.
    MsgBox "Opening workbook so values can be added.  Close when additions completed."
Else
    MsgBox ("Workbook B opened.  Testing value for " & item & " in column A:A in Workbook B")
    Set rng1 = Range(strRng).Find(item, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox item & " found !"
        Verify = True
        wbVerify.Close
        GoTo item_found
    Else
        MsgBox (item & " not found in column A:A.  Closing Workbook B.  *****User will be promoted at this point to exit, or re-open the file to modify the values so search value is found in column A:A.  Code SHOULD resume when Workbook B is closed.  Currently VBA code execution in Workbook A is stopping when the 'X' is selected in top right window of Workbook B*****")
        Verify = False
        wbVerify.Close
    End If


End If

Normal_exit:
Exit Function

item_found:
MsgBox "Verify code complete"
GoTo Normal_exit

End Function

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function


Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file.
'Returns FALSE if not existing, or if it's a folder
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function
```

Final code:

```
Global Const strWBb As String = "C:\Users\ashepherd\Desktop\WorkbookB.xlsx"
Global Const strRng As String = "A:A"
Global Complete As Boolean

Sub Validate()
' *****************************    CHECK WORKBOOK_B FOR 1 IN COLUMN A:A  *****************************
'  Verify presence on item in second workbook

searchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

Do While Verify(searchItem) = False

        Complete = False
        UserForm1.Show vbModeless       '  USerform has a single button which changes the global "Complete" variable to true
        Do While Complete = False
            DoEvents
        Loop
        UserForm1.Hide
        Debug.Print "Manual Edit Complete, retesting"
Loop

End Sub

Function Verify(item) As Boolean
'  Modified to close only upon finding search item vs. reopening it.

' ****************************************************************************
'  Open workbook B and verify that presence of item
' ****************************************************************************

Dim wbVerify As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range

' ************************** OPEN FILE ************************************************
If IsFile(strWBb) Then
    Set wbVerify = GetWorkbook(strWBb)

    If Not wbVerify Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print wbVerify.Name
    End If
    wbVerify.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Else
    MsgBox " File path incorrect.  Unable to open.", vbCritical
    Exit Function
End If

' ************************** TEST FOR ITEM ************************************************
Set rng1 = Range(strRng).Find(item, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Verify = True
    GoTo item_found
Else
    MsgBox (item & " not found in column A:A.   A pop up form will show.  Edit document and then hit RESUME button to continue checking.  DO NOT exit via the close icon in the top right window of Excel as the code will stop running.")
    Verify = False
End If

Normal_exit:
Exit Function

item_found:
'MsgBox (item & " found in WorkbookB, column A:A. Verify code complete")
wbVerify.Close Savechanges:=True
GoTo Normal_exit

End Function

Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file.
'Returns FALSE if not existing, or if it's a folder
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function

Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open, modified to add ignorereadonly and update links
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbReturn As Workbook

    sFile = Dir(sFullName)

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)

        If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
            Set wbReturn = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sFullName, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn
End Function
```

Comment: if the value is not in B, you can place it directly in there via code, if you know exactly where it needs to go. Closing the called workbook manually will halt code execution, because the code will lose touch with the workbook object and thus halt execution.

Comment: I've got a number of documents I need to check a few items each in. Nothing big that I think would be warranted to automate adding things via VBA.  I've managed to create a userform popup that will pause code where it is, then resume the code execution after user updates the forms.  Final code above if it helps anyone.