# VBA BeforeSave event crashes workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a template workbook that will be used on multiple projects. Each project will have their own folder and workbook, which can make it difficult to track them all down. Instead, I'm trying to create a BeforeSave event that will open another workbook and store this workbook's filepath on that workbook. The idea is that I can then call all saved workbooks to collect the data I need. I had it working, too, but I've encountered strange errors - workbook crashes and duplicate entries from the same event.

When the BeforeSave event is working, it adds 2-5 lines to the Project Collector instead of just once as expected. I've reviewed the code several times, but I don't see how or why it would repeat itself. It's not as if I'm pressing save multiple times, either, though the checks that I have should test for that anyway.

The main problem now is that lately the BeforeSave event will result in both workbooks forcibly closing. If the Project Collector workbook is closed the event will open the file, as expected, but it will crash before completion.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim PrevFilePath As String
    Dim NewFilePath As String
    ' turn off screen write to eliminate screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        If Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D70") <> Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName And _
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName <> "filepath\filename of template.xlsm" _
            Then 'if filepath or filename have changed since last opened, also does not trigger on the template file.
            PrevFilePath = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D70") 'store the previous filepath
            NewFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'store the current filepath
            Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D70") = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'write the current filepath on this workbook
            GoTo UpdateProjectCollector
            Else
        End If
        DoEvents
    
    UpdateProjectCollector:
        'open Project Collector
        Workbooks.Open "\\filepath\Project Collector.xlsm" 'open Project Collector
        If Workbooks("Project Collector.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(PrevFilePath) Is Nothing Then
            Workbooks("Project Collector.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = NewFilePath
            
            Else: Workbooks("Project Collector.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Replace What:=PrevFilePath, Replacement:=NewFilePath 'replace the previous filepath w/ the new filepath
        End If
        DoEvents
        
        Workbooks("Project Collector").Close SaveChanges:=True 'save & close Project Collector
    ' turn screen write back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Online resources suggested that perhaps one of the files is corrupted. I tried using the Open -> Open & Repair when opening a workbook, although that had no affect.

I re-created the Project Collector workbook entirely. I meant to save the code I had written for it, but forgot about it, and had to rewrite that book's code. This had no affect on the original workbook's ability to add its filepath to the Project Collector workbook.

I created a separate workbook where pressing a Command Button opens the Project Collector file and adds text 1 row below the bottom, just like with the original workbook - and it worked! This, combined with the fact that it was working before, suggests to me that it may not be the code, at least not in an obvious way.

I don't use 3rd party add-ins, and am only using the default references (Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library).

I'd be happy to hear of any solutions that don't result in a force close.

Comment: Not sure if this affects your problem, but it seems that the `GoTo UpdateProjectCollector` is not necessary and in fact skips the `DoEvents` call (which may or may not affect you). Also, I've occasionally run into issues opening other workbooks - using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382034/4717755) has helped.

Comment: In Excel 2010, the `Workbook_AfterSave` event was introduced. If your version is older, you'll be better off by utilizing the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. I mean, you don't know the new name before the workbook is saved. Try to explain step-by-step what needs to happen. Start with when you open the template and save it the first time with a new name... Also, share if you have any other events running.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the [`Application.EnableEvents = False`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents)?

Comment: No other events are running on this workbook. There are some Command buttons that do stuff, and 3 forms, but no events.

Comment: Commenting out Application.EnableEvents = False has no affect. I made the change, created a copy w/ a different name, opened the copy and saved, but the Project Collector workbook did not have the line on it. It did not, however, force crash on execution.

Comment: I believe I figured out a part of the problem. The PrevFilePath value was blank by default, and often what I used during testing. I added a check to determine if PrevFilePath = "", which will skip the .Find(PrevFilePath) and instead just write to the bottom-most row, just as if .Find(PrevFilePath) returns nothing. Before, it wouldn't add the filepath and it wouldn't replace anything because technically it was able to .Find blank cells in that range. Hoping this fixes the crashes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting here to resolve this thread. The PrevFilePath value was blank by default, and often what I used during testing. I added a check to determine if PrevFilePath = "", which will skip the .Find(PrevFilePath) and instead just write to the bottom-most row, just as if .Find(PrevFilePath) returns nothing. Before, it wouldn't add the filepath and it wouldn't replace anything because technically it was able to .Find blank cells in that range. Crashes have stopped as well.

Comment: This answer is a comment as @Sketchymage says.